# What's the behaviors of fields when finalize an object?

Tags: java, finalize

For example

```
class MyClass {
  private MyField1 f1;
  private MyField2 f2;

  @override
  protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("MyClass finalized.");
  }
}
```

When an instance of `MyClass` finalized, is `f1` and `f2` also finalized?
If `MyField1` and `MyField2` also have finalizer, what's the execution order among them?

Comment: What do you understand by the keyword `finalize`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, `f1` and `f2` are not automatically finalized.

They may well be referring to objects that could be scheduled for garbage collection at the same time as an instance of `MyClass`, assuming that nothing else is referring to the objects to which `f1` and `f2` are referring.

Adding an explicit finalizer to a class can interfere with the workings of the JVM, unless you adopt the idiom:

```
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    try {
        /*your finalize code*/
    } finally {
        super.finalize();
    }
}
```